# Php form submit, change to another page

Tags: php

I have a add.php file, its a form which collects data. When the user hits enter.submit button add.php will add the info to a database, then it should go to another page. It should redirect to a page(view.php). I have used

> header("Location: view.php");

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <?php
        include "library2.php";
        printHeader();
    ?>

    <title>Punch Electronics Inc.</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles.css">

     <nav>
    <ul>
            <li>
            <a href="add.php"> Add</a>
            </li>

            <li>
            <a href="view.php">View</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
</head> 

<body>
    <?php

        $itemNameErr ="";
        $descriptionErr ="";
        $suppCodeErr="";
        $costErr="";
        $sellingPriceErr="";
        $numberOnHandErr="";
        $reorderPointErr="";
        $dataValid = true;

        // If submit with POST
        if ($_POST) { 

            $itemName =  $_POST['itemName'];
            $description =  $_POST['description'];
            $suppCode = $_POST['suppCode'];
            $cost = $_POST['cost'];
            $sellingPrice = $_POST['sellingPrice'];
            $numberOnHand = $_POST['numberOnHand'];
            $reorderPoint = $_POST['reorderPoint'];

            //Check if empty, if not then check if it's valid.
            if ($itemName== "") {
                $itemNameErr = "Error! Please enter an item name.";
                $dataValid = false;
            }
            else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z :;\-,'0-9]{3,40}$/",$itemName))
            {
                $itemNameErr = "Error! Please enter a valid item.";
                $dataValid = false;        
            }

            if ($description == "") {
                $descriptionErr = "Error! Please enter a description.";
                $dataValid = false;        
            }
            else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z 0-9.,'\-\r\n]{4,2000}$/",$description))
                {
                    $descriptionErr = "Error! Please enter a valid item.";
                    $dataValid = false;        
                }

            if ($suppCode == "") {
                $suppCodeErr = "Error! Please enter a supplier code.";
                $dataValid = false;        
            }
            else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z \-0-9]{3,40}$/",$suppCode))
                {
                    $suppCodeErr = "Error! Please enter a valid supplier code.";
                    $dataValid = false;        
                }

            if ($cost == "") {
                $costErr = "Error! Please enter a cost";
                $dataValid = false;        
            }
            else if (!preg_match("/^\d{1,10}[.][0-9][0-9]$/",$cost))
                {
                    $costErr = "Error! Please enter a valid cost.";
                    $dataValid = false;        
                }

            if ($sellingPrice == "") {
                $sellingPriceErr = "Error! Please enter a selling price";
                $dataValid = false;        
            }
            else if (!preg_match("/^\d{1,10}[.][0-9][0-9]$/",$sellingPrice))
                {
                    $sellingPriceErr = "Error! Please enter a valid cost.";
                    $dataValid = false;        
                }

            if ($numberOnHand == "") {
                $numberOnHandErr = "Error! Please enter number on hand.";
                $dataValid = false;        
            }   
            else if (!preg_match("/^\d{1,}$/",$numberOnHand))
                {
                    $numberOnHandErr = "Error! Please enter a valid cost.";
                    $dataValid = false;        
                }

            if ($reorderPoint == "") {
                $reorderPointErr = "Error! Please enter reorder point.";
                $dataValid = false;        
            }
            else if (!preg_match("/^\d{1,}$/",$reorderPoint))
                {
                    $reorderPointErr = "Error! Please enter a valid cost.";
                    $dataValid = false;        
                }

        }


        //If submit with POST and Valid data.
        if ($_POST && $dataValid) { 

            $itemName = $_POST['itemName'];
            $description = $_POST['description'];
            $suppCode = $_POST['suppCode'];
            $cost = $_POST['cost'];
            $sellingPrice = $_POST['sellingPrice'];
            $numberOnHand = $_POST['numberOnHand'];
            $reorderPoint = $_POST['reorderPoint'];
            if($_POST['backOrder']==="yes")
            {
                $backOrder = "y";
            }
            else $backOrder = "n";

            $link = connectMysql();
            $sql_query = "INSERT INTO inventory VALUES ('','$itemName', '$description', '$suppCode', '$cost','$sellingPrice', '$numberOnHand','$reorderPoint', '$backOrder', 'n');";
            $result = runQuery($link, $sql_query);
            //Change to view.php after successfully posted and inserted into database.
            header("Location: view.php");
    ?>

    <?php
        // If no submit or data is invalid, print form, repopulating fields and print error msg
        } else { 
    ?>
</br></br></br>
 <div id="requirement">
    All fields in <span>*</span> are mandatory.
 </div>
 <div id="form">
  <form action="" id= "add" method="post">
    <table>

    <tr>
        <td>Item Name: </td>
    <td><input id="itemInput" name="itemName" type="text" value="<?php  if (isset($_POST['itemName'])) echo $_POST['itemName']; ?>"><span >* <?php echo $itemNameErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Description:</td>
    <td><textarea rows="10" cols="40"  name="description" type="text"><?php if (isset($_POST['description'])) echo $_POST['description']; ?></textarea><span>* <?php echo $descriptionErr;?></></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Supplier Code:</td>
    <td><input id="suppInput" name="suppCode" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['suppCode'])) echo $_POST['suppCode']; ?>"><span >* <?php echo $suppCodeErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cost:</td>
    <td><input name="cost" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['cost'])) echo $_POST['cost']; ?>"><span >* <?php echo $costErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Selling Price:</td>
    <td><input name="sellingPrice" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['sellingPrice'])) echo $_POST['sellingPrice']; ?>"><span >* <?php echo $sellingPriceErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number On Hand:</td>
    <td><input name="numberOnHand" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['numberOnHand'])) echo $_POST['numberOnHand']; ?>"><span >* <?php echo $numberOnHandErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Reorder Point:</td>
    <td><input name="reorderPoint" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['reorderPoint'])) echo $_POST['reorderPoint']; ?>"><span >* <?php echo $reorderPointErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>On Back Order:</td>
    <td>
        <input name="backOrder" type="checkbox" value="yes" <?php if (isset($_POST['backOrder'])) echo 'checked'; ?> />
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input name="submit" type="submit"></td>
    </table>
    </tr>

  </form>
  </div>

    <?php
            }
    ?>

</body>

<footer>
    <?php
        printFooter();
    ?>
</footer>
```

library2.php:

```
<?php
        //Function to connect to MYSQL server
        function connectMysql(){

            $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'bti-mysql', 'mysqlrocks!',  'bti320')
            //$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '',  'bti320')
                or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link));

            return $link;
        }
    ?>
    <?php
        //Function to run the given query, requires $link from connect and SQL query
        function runQuery($link, $sql_query){

            $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql_query) or die('query failed'. mysqli_error($link));
            return $result;
        }
    ?>
    <?php
        //Function to display logo/header.
        function printHeader()
        {
    ?>
        <img id="logo" src="logo.png" alt="openclipart.org CC creative commons" height="275" width="420">

    <?php
        }
    ?>

    <?php
        //Function to display footer.
        function printFooter()
        {
    ?>
            Copyright © 2015 Shashank Inc.
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Post your code. Where did you add `header("Location: view.php");` What errors did you see?

Comment: Uh... use HTML? Exactly what are you expecting us to to? Tell you what color to use on the page? What data to put on it? That's NOT what we're here for... Your lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities are just begging to get your site and server destroyed... so you've got that going for you, at least.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: guess in the wild, you should add the `header()` before any code is outputted to the browser (before any echo, whitespace, anything). If this is not the case, it will not work

Comment: Explain the question didnt understood

Comment: okay, lets say the user fills the form up. when they click submit it adds to the database, that’s all. After its done i need to go to some other page

Comment: Please, paste here also library2.php

Comment: i updated, i included that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use

```
header("Location: view.php");
```

before any other output to the page.

Post here content of add.php

This is new content of add.php:

```
<?php
        include "library2.php";

        $itemNameErr ="";
        $descriptionErr ="";
        $suppCodeErr="";
        $costErr="";
        $sellingPriceErr="";
        $numberOnHandErr="";
        $reorderPointErr="";
        $dataValid = true;

        // If submit with POST
        if ($_POST) { 

            $itemName =  $_POST['itemName'];
            $description =  $_POST['description'];
            $suppCode = $_POST['suppCode'];
            $cost = $_POST['cost'];
            $sellingPrice = $_POST['sellingPrice'];
            $numberOnHand = $_POST['numberOnHand'];
            $reorderPoint = $_POST['reorderPoint'];

            //Check if empty, if not then check if it's valid.
            if ($itemName== "") {
                $itemNameErr = "Error! Please enter an item name.";
                $dataValid = false;
            }
            else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z :;\-,'0-9]{3,40}$/",$itemName))
            {
                $itemNameErr = "Error! Please enter a valid item.";
                $dataValid = false;        
            }

            if ($description == "") {
                $descriptionErr = "Error! Please enter a description.";
                $dataValid = false;        
            }
            else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z 0-9.,'\-\r\n]{4,2000}$/",$description))
                {
                    $descriptionErr = "Error! Please enter a valid item.";
                    $dataValid = false;        
                }

            if ($suppCode == "") {
                $suppCodeErr = "Error! Please enter a supplier code.";
                $dataValid = false;        
            }
            else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z \-0-9]{3,40}$/",$suppCode))
                {
                    $suppCodeErr = "Error! Please enter a valid supplier code.";
                    $dataValid = false;        
                }

            if ($cost == "") {
                $costErr = "Error! Please enter a cost";
                $dataValid = false;        
            }
            else if (!preg_match("/^\d{1,10}[.][0-9][0-9]$/",$cost))
                {
                    $costErr = "Error! Please enter a valid cost.";
                    $dataValid = false;        
                }

            if ($sellingPrice == "") {
                $sellingPriceErr = "Error! Please enter a selling price";
                $dataValid = false;        
            }
            else if (!preg_match("/^\d{1,10}[.][0-9][0-9]$/",$sellingPrice))
                {
                    $sellingPriceErr = "Error! Please enter a valid cost.";
                    $dataValid = false;        
                }

            if ($numberOnHand == "") {
                $numberOnHandErr = "Error! Please enter number on hand.";
                $dataValid = false;        
            }   
            else if (!preg_match("/^\d{1,}$/",$numberOnHand))
                {
                    $numberOnHandErr = "Error! Please enter a valid cost.";
                    $dataValid = false;        
                }

            if ($reorderPoint == "") {
                $reorderPointErr = "Error! Please enter reorder point.";
                $dataValid = false;        
            }
            else if (!preg_match("/^\d{1,}$/",$reorderPoint))
                {
                    $reorderPointErr = "Error! Please enter a valid cost.";
                    $dataValid = false;        
                }

        }


            if ($_POST && $dataValid) {

            $itemName = $_POST['itemName'];
            $description = $_POST['description'];
            $suppCode = $_POST['suppCode'];
            $cost = $_POST['cost'];
            $sellingPrice = $_POST['sellingPrice'];
            $numberOnHand = $_POST['numberOnHand'];
            $reorderPoint = $_POST['reorderPoint'];
            if($_POST['backOrder']==="yes")
            {
                $backOrder = "y";
            }
            else $backOrder = "n";

            $link = connectMysql();
            $sql_query = "INSERT INTO inventory VALUES ('','$itemName', '$description', '$suppCode', '$cost','$sellingPrice', '$numberOnHand','$reorderPoint', '$backOrder', 'n');";
            $result = runQuery($link, $sql_query);
            //Change to view.php after successfully posted and inserted into database.
            header("Location: view.php");
        }
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <?php
        //include "library2.php";
        printHeader();
    ?>

    <title>Punch Electronics Inc.</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles.css">

     <nav>
    <ul>
            <li>
            <a href="add.php"> Add</a>
            </li>

            <li>
            <a href="view.php">View</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
</head> 

<body>
    <?php

        if ($_POST && $dataValid) {
        // If no submit or data is invalid, print form, repopulating fields and print error msg
        } else { 
    ?>
</br></br></br>
 <div id="requirement">
    All fields in <span>*</span> are mandatory.
 </div>
 <div id="form">
  <form action="" id= "add" method="post">
    <table>

    <tr>
        <td>Item Name: </td>
    <td><input id="itemInput" name="itemName" type="text" value="<?php  if (isset($_POST['itemName'])) echo $_POST['itemName']; ?>"><span >* <?php echo $itemNameErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Description:</td>
    <td><textarea rows="10" cols="40"  name="description" type="text"><?php if (isset($_POST['description'])) echo $_POST['description']; ?></textarea><span>* <?php echo $descriptionErr;?></></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Supplier Code:</td>
    <td><input id="suppInput" name="suppCode" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['suppCode'])) echo $_POST['suppCode']; ?>"><span >* <?php echo $suppCodeErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cost:</td>
    <td><input name="cost" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['cost'])) echo $_POST['cost']; ?>"><span >* <?php echo $costErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Selling Price:</td>
    <td><input name="sellingPrice" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['sellingPrice'])) echo $_POST['sellingPrice']; ?>"><span >* <?php echo $sellingPriceErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number On Hand:</td>
    <td><input name="numberOnHand" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['numberOnHand'])) echo $_POST['numberOnHand']; ?>"><span >* <?php echo $numberOnHandErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>Reorder Point:</td>
    <td><input name="reorderPoint" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['reorderPoint'])) echo $_POST['reorderPoint']; ?>"><span >* <?php echo $reorderPointErr;?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>On Back Order:</td>
    <td>
        <input name="backOrder" type="checkbox" value="yes" <?php if (isset($_POST['backOrder'])) echo 'checked'; ?> />
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input name="submit" type="submit"></td>
    </table>
    </tr>

  </form>
  </div>

    <?php
            }
    ?>

</body>

<footer>
    <?php
        printFooter();
    ?>
</footer>
```

Comment: It just goes blank, and it didnt even add to the database

Comment: It should work, please check, if you copied correctly add.php source code. if you want, I can also simulate database. But code its ok, please check it once again, what I posted here. Example - http://x.poslatsms.sk/add.php

Comment: It should work on both. Does it throw any error on CentOs? I tested it also on CentOs (the link I sent you). To see any errors (not only blank page), add at the beginning of code this: <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?> Of course on CentOs you are using different connection string to database, so please check it, if its correct...

Comment: There are no errors displaying, but now it show the page. But it doesnt go to view.php. the form is gone, but in the address bar its still in add.php

Comment: Did you changed something? That now its ok, and before it wasnt? I didnt change my code.

Comment: So does it add record to database? and after that it should redirect to view.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39310/discussion-between-legionar-and-hank99)

Answer (score 3):

You have html being output before the header("Location: view.PHP")... That means headers are already sent.

Comment: Yea i know, is there any other way to change page?

Comment: Mine code is correct, but please check it once again, if you there is any other error. Of course on CentOs you are using different connection string to database, so please check it...

Answer (score 2):

I test your code, place of header("Location: view.php"); is ok.

check your database commands? {maybe header("Location: view.php")} never run and your database commands raise a error!!!
good lock